# Props data how to manipulate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `<WithCallbacks options={options} />` , where `options` = `array [{value:,label:}...]`

How to bind this options to component, and manipulate with FilterColors, becuase I am getting my options and having error in `i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())`

```
export default class WithCallbacks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    };
    const options = this.props.options
    this.filterColors = this.filterColors.bind(this)
  }

  filterColors = (inputValue) => {
    return this.options.filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  };
  loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(filterColors(inputValue));
    }, 100);
  };
  handleInputChange = (newValue) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    return inputValue;
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.options)
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>inputValue: "{this.state.inputValue}"</pre>
        <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
          defaultOptions
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: @AdamAzad I got as drop-list my options, but when i  put some text, error in i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())

Comment: I think you are using this.options.filter but you should use this.props.options.filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `constructor`, `options` is defined, but as a local variable in the scope of `constructor`. For `options` to be accessible by other methods of `WithCallbacks`, define as

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    };
    this.options = this.props.options; // prepend this
    this.filterColors = this.filterColors.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: TypeError: i.label.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: @JessicaBulldog, are you sure that `label` is a String?